# Connection to MongoDB with Mongoose not working

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, database-connection

I created a new mongoDB database and used Express generator to create my backend folder. I want to make a connection to my mongoDB database using Mongoose.

I tried this:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

var options = {
   connectTimeoutMS: 5000,
   useNewUrlParser: true,
  };

mongoose.connect('mongodb+srv://UserName:<password>@cluster1-hxnnz.azure.mongodb.net/CollectionName?retryWrites=true&w=majority',
    options,
    function(err) {
     if (err) {
       console.log(err);
     } else {
       console.info('connection ok');
     }
    }
);

module.exports = mongoose;
```

`Username` `Password` and `CollectionName` are correctly replaced, I use the link that mongodb gives me to make a connection.
Nothing is happening, no console log is displayed. I tried other solutions of the forum and the code given by mongoose but without success

- mongoose: 5.9.4,
- express: 4.16.1,

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Best start is to test your connection using some client like mongo compass or robo3T, next what is this `ClusterName` ? It has to be your DB name !! So either error log or **connection ok** has to be printed, nothing gets printed ? then check whether this file is being called or not !! Or write a simple js file just for connection & test it first & then put that code in ur node.js project..

Comment: I edited the post, Cluster Name is the name of the collection that will be created during the first connection if it does not already exist. I can connect to mongo compass using my connection string, what should I do on it ? when i start the server with npm start, express starts correctly. It looks like the connection file to mongoDB is not read but I don't know how to check

Comment: I don't understand because, the code works very well with another connection string from another MongoDB cluster

Comment: the post is closed, I found the solution. I simply forgot the ` require('./models/bddconnect'); ` in app.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code works fine. I think this is your DB file(db.js) you just need to import it in 
  your starter file (app.js) require('./db');

```
 const mongoose = require('mongoose');
 var options = {
  connectTimeoutMS: 5000,
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  };

mongoose.connect('mongodb+srv://UserName:<password>@cluster1-hxnnz.azure.mongodb.net/CollectionName?retryWrites=true&w=majority',
options,
function(err) {
 if (err) {
   console.log(err);
 } else {
   console.info('connection ok');
 }
}
);

module.exports = mongoose;
```

and for your security purpose separate MongoDB's link from that file

Comment: Yep it's working when i don't forget to import my db.js in my starter file ! And thanks for the tip about the security